# How to check if private/public key pair match

Tags: .net, encryption

Currently, I`m doing this by encrypting some data with a public key and then decrypting with a private key.

Decryption will fail if the pair didn't match.

```cs
using System.Security.Cryptography;

var rsa = RSA.Create();

var publicKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey);
rsa.ImportRSAPublicKey(publicKeyBytes, out var _);
var encryptedBytes = rsa.Encrypt(new byte[] {}, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);

var privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey);
rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(privateKeyBytes, out var _);
var decryptedBytes = rsa.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
```

if the public-private key pair didn't match, decryption will fail with `CryptographicException`

Is there a more elegant way to validate this pair using .NET build-in (`System.Security`) stuff?

*P.S. it's a bit irrelevant to the question, but is it OK to do this kind of validation on an application startup?*

Comment: `ImportFromPem` might be easier. And `TryEncrypt` and `TryDecrypt` might be safer also. These are all only available in .NET 5+

Comment: Unfortunately, `TryDecrypt` throws `WindowsCryptographicException` in case of invalid keys (and you cannot catch it by type, only as a generic exception).

Comment: Also, in my case, PEM is irrelevant, as it's not the way we store keys.